# Is there a way to disable warnings in vim quickfix?

Tags: vim

i am pretty new to vim and i find the warnings in quickfix especially distracting and useless at times. Is there a way to let quickfix ignore warnings and only highlight errors? Thank you for your help.

Comment: it sometime depends on what you are using it for , some are mostly `linter` so you can remove or disable the `linter`. If you provide me with the programming language, I may be able to help

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you to configure your compiler or linter to show warnings or not.

How to do so depends on your compiler or linter, which we don't know anything about.

Comment: This seems much more like a comment than an answer (regardless of the fact that the question seems a little vague, or needing details/focus).